# Populate gridview only on button click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

My page consists of 4 text boxes (query filters), a submit button, and a gridview. The gridview data source is configured to take text from the 4 text boxes and filter the query results. This part works great.

This issue comes about in that for the query to function, I can't have empty text boxes or the query won't function. Something must be entered, or % for wildcard.

To be friendly for my users, I tried to set a default value of % for each of the 4 control sources(text boxes) in the gridview  Data source configuration. However, since the gridview automatically populates on page load, this doesn't work since all 4 controls are set to wildcard. And when you have a DB that has hundreds of thousands of rows......

TL/DR: I want my gridview to only populate on button click, and I want blank text boxes to be accepted as wildcard (%). Ive tried a couple different code snippits concerning IsPostBack, but they didn't seem to do anything.  Language = VB. Any tips you good folks can provide would be greatly appreciated.  asp below:

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TaxRollConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [OWNER], [ADDRESS1], [ADDRESS2], [ADDRESS3], [CITY], [STATE], [ZIP], [WELL], [YEARBEGAN], [OPERATOR], [SURVEY], [ACRES], [TYPE], [INTEREST], [VALUE], [YEAR], [COUNTY] FROM [Owner] WHERE (([OWNER] LIKE '%' + @OWNER + '%') AND ([WELL] LIKE '%' + @WELL + '%') AND ([OPERATOR] LIKE '%' + @OPERATOR + '%') AND ([COUNTY] LIKE '%' + @COUNTY + '%'))">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="textOwner" Name="OWNER" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="textWell" Name="WELL" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="textOp" Name="OPERATOR" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="textCo" Name="COUNTY" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OWNER" HeaderText="OWNER" SortExpression="OWNER" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ADDRESS1" HeaderText="ADDRESS1" SortExpression="ADDRESS1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ADDRESS2" HeaderText="ADDRESS2" SortExpression="ADDRESS2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ADDRESS3" HeaderText="ADDRESS3" SortExpression="ADDRESS3" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CITY" HeaderText="CITY" SortExpression="CITY" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="STATE" HeaderText="STATE" SortExpression="STATE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ZIP" HeaderText="ZIP" SortExpression="ZIP" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WELL" HeaderText="WELL" SortExpression="WELL" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="YEARBEGAN" HeaderText="YEARBEGAN" SortExpression="YEARBEGAN" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OPERATOR" HeaderText="OPERATOR" SortExpression="OPERATOR" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SURVEY" HeaderText="SURVEY" SortExpression="SURVEY" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ACRES" HeaderText="ACRES" SortExpression="ACRES" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TYPE" HeaderText="TYPE" SortExpression="TYPE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="INTEREST" HeaderText="INTEREST" SortExpression="INTEREST" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VALUE" HeaderText="VALUE" SortExpression="VALUE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="YEAR" HeaderText="YEAR" SortExpression="YEAR" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="COUNTY" HeaderText="COUNTY" SortExpression="COUNTY" />
        </Columns>
```

CodeBehind:

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    textOwner.Text = ""
    textWell.Text = ""
    textCo.Text = ""
    textOp.Text = ""
End Sub
```

End Class

---

**EDIT**

I managed to fix my two main issues by removing the datasourceID from the gridview, and the following executed on click:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Call BindData()
End Sub

Private Sub BindData()
    With GridView1
        .DataSource = SqlDataSource1
        .DataBind()
    End With
End Sub
```

However, in doing so I've managed to break the table sorting capability of the gridview. I suppose I'll find a way to do the sorting client side.

Comment: Share your code behind file.

Comment: nothing there really. Just some code to clear/reset my query fields via a button click. I added it to the main post